# Does Destiny 2 have a free trial?

Tags: destiny-2

I expected the game to have a limited trial version like the other paid Blizzard games* (barring Overwatch) Diablo III, World of Warcraft and Starcraft 2 (before switching to free-to-play). Installation option was missing in the Battle.net client, but I assumed that this is a bug [as so was reported on the forum](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20759488418#detail). I had to use [an alternative method](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20759488418#post-19) to install the game. I get [SAXOPHONE error code](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/46139) briefly after launching.

*Activision, the publisher of Destiny 2, is a subsidiary of [Activision Blizzard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activision_Blizzard)

Is there a permanent trial of Destiny 2 or has the game only been playable during special events such as "free weekends"?

Comment: On PC Gaming Wiki "free trial" is listed as one game version: https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Destiny_2#Version_differences

Comment: The top hit on google was this: https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/46488 . Was there something that this didn't answer?

Comment: @Chris: No there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bungie has announced a [free-to-play version](https://www.bungie.net/7/en/Destiny/NewLight) of Destiny 2:

> Destiny 2: New Light launches October 1, 2019 and is free to play on every supported platform.

Answer (score 2):

There was a free trial weekend, there is not (as of this answer) a permanent free trial.

The **SAXOPHONE** error help page on Bungie.net (That you linked to) makes this very clear.

> Players do not own Destiny 2, but have it installed from a Free Trial weekend and are attempting to launch outside of a promotional window.

---

On top of that, **Activision** and **Blizzard Entertainment** are still separately run Business Units underneath the wider **Activision Blizzard** entity. Calling Destiny 2 a "Blizzard" game, is not technically correct as Blizzard Entertainment (the game development company), had nothing to do with the development of Destiny 2, besides allowing Activision to use their Battle.Net content delivery platform.